# MongoDB C# Driver: How do I ensure an index using LINQ expressions on the contents of an array?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

How can I ensure an index using LINQ expressions on the contents of an array using the MongoDB C# driver?

I currently have a domain object that looks roughly like this:

```
public class Team
{
    public Team()
    {
        Members = new List<LazyReference>();
    }

    public MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public LazyReference Leader { get; set; }
    public List<LazyReference> Members { get; private set; }
}

public class LazyReference
{
    public MongoDB.Bson.ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}
```

On my collection, I have initialized a couple of indexes like this:

```
collection.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys<Team>.Ascending(t => t.DisplayName), IndexOptions.SetUnique(true));
collection.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys<Team>.Ascending(t => t.Leader.Id), IndexOptions.SetUnique(false));
```

How can I do the same to ensure a fast index of the Members when looking up by Members[n].Id, where n is any of the members?  I am aware that I can create an index as follows, but since this does not use the LINQ expressions, it is not safe for future renames of properties.

```
collection.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder().Ascending("Members._id"), IndexOptions.SetUnique(false));
```

I have also tried the following, but it only indexes the index specified:

```
collection.EnsureIndex(IndexKeys<Team>.Ascending(t => t.Members[0].Id), IndexOptions.SetUnique(false));
```

Comment: Is `LazyReference` your own class? Could you post its code or describe its purpose?

Comment: @ZaidMasud, I've updated to include a basic declaration of LazyReference.  Ultimately, what I've provided is all that is relevant to this example, since the rest are methods and non-persisted properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following:

```
await collection.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<Team>.IndexKeys.Ascending($"{nameof(Team.Members)}.{nameof(LazyReference.Id)}"), new CreateIndexOptions() { Unique = false });
```

this protects from property renaming but still not as elegant as Linq. The above code creates an index like `{ "Members._id" : 1 }`.

Comment: That looks like it'd work; of course, when I asked the question, `nameof` was not an option! Unfortunately, I'm long past being able to test this out, but I'm going to accept this anyway. Thanks for sharing!